# Execute java file on Google Compute Engine from desktop application/outside application

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have created an instance of GCE(with persistan disk) and successfully able to ssh to that instance from my machine using gcutil. Now let's say I have stored some java program/class file/jar file in GCE instance disk
/home/abc/a.java

Now I want to run this from my local machine programatically using java. Please guide me how can I do the same.?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to expose your java program as a RESTful web service and call it via HTTP from your local machine's client code.

Otherwise you will need to figure out how to [standard ssh](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances#standardssh) into Google Compute Engine. Then use either Java or Gradle tasks to ssh in and call your program.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to compile the Java program a.java eg:

```
javac a.java
```

Then you could execute the resulting /home/abc/a.class file locally (executing from working directory /home/abc/):

```
# If OS is RHEL 7:
java -cp /home/abc a
```

But since you want to execute a by remote invocation, you could execute it instead by ssh. Use the same remote ssh client commandline execution from your local machine that you use to login to that GCE instance, but append to it the command to execute eg:

```
# If GCE is RHEL 7:
ssh -i ~/.ssh/gce.pub -c des -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc@110.42.53.22 'java -cp /home/abc a'
```

Note that that commandline assumes that your GCE account's public key is in (local) ~/.ssh/gce.pub and that abc is the GCE username (as you indicated) and that 110.42.53.22 is a made-up IP# that you replace with the external IP# of your GCE instance. Revise to suit your actual conditions.